# Object and String parameter

Tags: java

I am learning through w3schools. I am confused mainly about the meaning of java syntax. To my understanding, both functions the same except for the String cases.
The thing I don't understand is their parameters; why is the other an Object and the other is String?

```
public boolean equals(Object anotherObject)
```

```
public boolean equalsIgnoreCase(String anotherString)
```

Comment: Why bet instead of reading some doc? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)

Comment: @fantaghirocco: JavaDoc is good at explaining the "what", but not really at explaining the "why", especially for developers that are not experienced already (reading the "why" often requires lots of context and reading between the lines).

Comment: @JoachimSauer yes, thank you. I already looked at both functions with the use of eclipse but made it hard to grasp the idea!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`equals(Object)` is defined in `java.lang.Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and is a method that is available on all object in Java. Therefore it's defined as generically as possible (i.e. it accepts any other object as the argument).

[`equalsIgnoreCase` is only defined in `java.lang.String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)). It's a *specific* method for comparing strings in a *specific* way. Since it's about text, it doesn't make sense to accept any non-`String` object here.

Answer (score 1):

Great question! I'm not a Java expert so don't just take my word for it :)

The [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))
function is declared in `Object`, which is the superclass of `String`. It is declared in a way, to support comparison to any object, not just strings.

In contrast, the [`equalsIgnoreCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String))
is a function specific to just strings, it is declared in the `String` class. It is made for comparison between strings only.

Answer (score 0):

Only strings can have both upper and lower case, and in the case of the first one it is checking if 2 objects are equal, no matter if they are string or not so cases do not matter